# How do you understand WebStorm's function interfaces?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I am having trouble understanding some functions, and their interfaces. IE:

```
ReadonlyArray<unknown>.map( 
    callbackfn: (value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => unknown,
    thisArg?: any): unknown[]
```

This is what WebStorm displays when I hover over a `.map()` function. I understand that `.map()` takes a specified callback function as a parameter, but what do `=> unknown`, and `thisArg?: any` represent?

Likewise when I hover over a `forEach()` function, the popup looks like this:

```
ReadonlyArray<unknown>.forEach(
     callbackfn: (value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => void,
     thisArg?: any): void
```

forEach also takes a callback function as a parameter, but what does `=> void, thisArg?: any): void` represent?

Comment: The types are shown in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// the `.map` function is member of the generic type ReadonlyArray<unknown>. Where unknown is the type of the elements of the array
ReadonlyArray<unknown>.map( 
    // first argument is a callback function. The first argument of the callback is value, of type unknown, the second is index of type number, and so on
    callbackfn: (value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) 
       // this parts means that the callback should return a value of type unknown
       => unknown,
    // .map takes a second arguments called thisArg of any type. The ? means that the argument is optional
    thisArg?: any)
    // .map returns an array of type unknown
    : unknown[]
```

The type is unknown because it depends on the type of the elements present in the array on which `.map` is applied. If it is an array of object, the unknown type will be `object`

Similarly, `forEach` takes a first argument which is a callback. But the callback returns nothing, hence you have `=> void`.

Comment: So does the '?' after thisArg mean it's optional?

Comment: it does (I edited the answer)